# How do I interpret Bittrex's minimum trade size?

Tags: trade, bittrex

The following description from https://bittrex.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001473863-Bittrex-Trading-Rules confuses me:

> All cryptocurrency orders placed on the Bittrex platform are subject
>   to the following minimum order sizes:
>
> The minimum trade size is 50,000 Satoshis. There is also a minimum
>   trade quantity.  For example, DOGE trades at 22 satoshis.  The minimum
>   trade quantity is 4500 DOGE and the minimum trade value is 50,000
>   Satoshis.  The smallest order in the book is 50000 DOGE at 1 satoshi
>   each.  The largest order in the book is 4500 DOGE at 2 btc each.

So if I have the BTC-DOGE pair for example. The https://api.bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkets API says MinTradeSize = 480. I assume this means the minimum quantity of DOGE I can buy is 480. How does the minimum trade size of 50,000 satoshi from the trading rules above work with this?

Does it mean `X DOGE x current price >= 50,000 satoshi` and `X DOGE >= 480` for a trade to be accepted?

I have tested the first comparison (`X DOGE x current price >= 50,000 satoshi`) which seems to be correct. However I am unable to test the second (`X DOGE >= 480`).

Also what happens when the quote currency is USD, USDT or ETH?